# Background-color of an image is sometimes displayed outside a container

Tags: html, css

I want to display some shapes with color adjusted dynamically. To this end, I prepared all shapes as images with transparency in areas inside the shape and white color outside. To change a color of a shape, I simply set the `background-color` property of an `img` element.

The problem is that I may sometimes see 1-pixel wide lines on the edges of the image. Such line on the top of the image is visible in Google Chrome for Android, while in the PC version this issue can be seen once the page is zoomed in. The problem doesn't occur in Firefox. Here's a [sample code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyd6xs5u/7/) (updated).

What's more, the issue doesn't occur if I remove the outer `div` element or its style (I added it, because I want the page to be centered both horizontally and vertically).

I'm looking for any solution: either some hack to fix my code or another way to achieve my goal of coloring shapes dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to find a working solution:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This has to be added to the style of the main container, which has the `transform` property applied. `overflow: hidden;` is not needed.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyd6xs5u/8/).

Answer (score 1):

What I can see in  your code is that line is overflowing outside. You can just add `overflow:hidden` to the `div` element.
see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyd6xs5u/5/)

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);overflow:hidden;">
  <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/vipedk1qd/arrow_up.png" style="background-color: red;" />
</div>
```

Comment: This solves the problem in this particular case, but look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lyd6xs5u/7/

With `overflow: hidden;` the line is visible once you zoom the page.

I updated the link in the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes.. Thats true.. And the other solution provided by cupawn also suffers the same problem.. A better solution is required..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a glitch in GPU-accelerated compositing. If you don't need the `transform` property in the CSS, removing it should solve the problem for you (at least it does for me in Chrome on OS X). In this case, you could (for example) use negative margins instead

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin: -25px 0 0 -27px">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/vipedk1qd/arrow_up.png" style="background-color: #000000;"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyd6xs5u/2/